# Arabic encoding with tomcat and mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, arabic-support

i have tomcat server and mysql 
when insert data with Arabic it appears like '???? ????'

i change MySQL database with

> ALTER DATABASE database name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

it did not work

and try in tomcat server.xml 
change it to

> Encouraging="UTF-8" on each Connector tag in the server.xml file

it still appears like  '???? ??????'

can any one help me please